# Issue With Tridion Smart Target 2011 Sp3

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget

[image: Smart Target]

Error Throwing while clicking on Smart target icon from Content Manager. Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: We'll need some more details to help here - is it a new installation or upgrade? Which version of Tridion? Did it work before?

Comment: Hi Nuno- The SDL 2013 Sp1 is installed and running website with Experience Manager. This is new installation for SmartTarget 2011 SP3. We installed conponents-Fredhopper Server,Smart target installer for Content Manager and Content Delivery. Is Smart Target 2011 Sp3 is  Competible with Tridion 213 SP1?

Comment: According to the docs - http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2/concept_FCF26E1B68924C999C67062731E92FED - no, it is not compatible. You need to use SmartTarget 2014 SP1: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1&lang=en-US, see upgrade options here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-46984C71-1EE0-4D96-9391-78E08A05F458

Comment: Thanks nuno. I used wrong installer previously. Now I am able to installed it properly.

Comment: Add all this info as an answer, then accept it. It might help others.